# Killing all redirects

Tags: php, apache

I have a script that has a very long execution time (several hours) and redirects recursively to itself if there are memory / timeout errors.
I use `try{} catch(){}` for the redirection.

Sometimes I will want to stop execution midway, and the only way I've come up with to do this is resetting the apache. This is sub-optimal, since the server runs several sites.

Is there a more precise way to stop a script or at least block it from redirecting?

Comment: use an external sentinel. e.g. check for the presence/absence of a file.

Comment: kill the process `kill -pid`

Comment: I assume your script has a loop or some opportunity to repeatedly check some value. You could set a `$stopExecution` variable in another thread. Can you use threads in your PHP project?

Comment: @Dai I can check values at the top of the redirect(It redirects every 5-10 minutes). This seems like a nice solution. Do you know of a good link where I can learn about using threads?